# Kivy: Switch reads the value from the INI file

Tags: kivy, switch-statement

```
kvstring = Builder.load_string('''
<AccParGui>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Accordion:
             AccordionItem:
                title: 'EIP'
                BoxLayout:
                     Button:
                        text: 'Into EIP'
                     GridLayout:
                        cols: 2
                        Label:
                            text: "refresh: "
                        Switch:
                            id: switch_eip_refresh
                            active: True
                            on_active: root.switch_eip_callback()
        AccordionItem:
            title: 'About'
            Label:
                text: 'Financial work aids'
''')

class BrowserPlatform():
    def switch_eip_callback():
        if self.set_refresh:
            accpar_config.set('General', 'set_refresh', 'False') #write INI
            self.ids.switch_eip_refresh.active = False
            self.set_refresh = False
            self.event_homepage_refresh.cancel()
        else:
            accpar_config.set('General', 'set_refresh', 'True')
            self.ids.switch_eip_refresh.active = True
            self.set_refresh = True
            self.event_homepage_refresh = Clock.schedule_interval(
            self.eip_refresh, self.set_refresh_time)

class AccParGui(Widget, BrowserPlatform
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ids.switch_eip_refresh.active = accpar_config.getboolean('General', 'set_refresh')
        # read from ini

class AccParGuiApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return AccParGui()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    AccParGuiApp().run()
```

I use Switch to toggle values. If the Switch value read in the .INI file is False, the on_active event is executed automatically (True is not ).
I understand that the value of Switch is property, Kivy is automatically monitored. Even if I don't click Switch. But my intention is to change only by clicking. How can I do that? Hope someone advises, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `on_active` event gets triggered when the `active` property changes. Since your `Switch` starts with `active: True`, the `True` value from your `.INI` is not a change and does not trigger the event.

An ugly hack to protect the `switch_eip_callback()` method from unintended execution is to just set a Boolean variable (perhaps named `ignore_active_change`), and check that variable in the `switch_eip_callback()`. If that variable is `True`, just set it back to `False` and return.

Here is a simple example of what I mean:

```
class AccParGuiApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = Builder.load_string(kvstring)
        self.ignore_switch_activity = True  # ignore any changes in switch activity
        root.ids.switch_eip_refresh.active = Config.getboolean('app', 'switch')
        self.ignore_switch_activity = False  # stop ignoring
        return root

    def switch_eip_callback(self):
        if self.ignore_switch_activity:
            print('ignoring switch')
        else:
            print('not ignoring switch')
```

Comment: I'm new to Python and still have no idea after thinking about it for a day. Can you give a snippet code? Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much for your careful help for a novice！

Comment: Looking at it carefully, it feels like there's something wrong with your code: self.ignore_switch_activity = True -------- is true , But the third line becomes false.   If  judge again in the function,  need to click twice when click manually

Comment: The code in the `build()` methods prevents the loading of the switch setting using `Config` from triggering code. It is set back to False to allow the triggering.

Comment: I tried again, and the code didn't work as expected: different values in the INI file still automatically triggered the switch_eip_callback() function.